# I am not able to connect to OPC DA server remotely from client machine

Tags: c#, asp.net, server, remote-server, opc-da

I am not able to connect to OPC DA server hosted on a remote server(AZURE VM) from a client machine.

Initially i was getting the "**CoCreateIstance excdeption: class not registered**" that i resolved by installing the OPC Core Components on the client machine.

Now i am getting the below error while trying to connect to OPCDA server from .NET Service:

```
Could not connect to server.
Matrikon.OPC.Simulation.1
**************** Exception Details ****************
 Exception occurrred at : 7/21/2020 7:43:47 PM
 Source :  OpcNetApi
 **Message :  E_NETWORK_ERROR**
Could not connect to server.
Matrikon.OPC.Simulation.1
 Type :  Opc.ConnectFailedException
 Inner Exception :  
 Stack Trace :     at Opc.Server.Connect(URL url, ConnectData connectData)
   at Opc.Da.Server.Connect(URL url, ConnectData connectData)
   at Opc.Server.Connect()
```

I tried to modify the DCOM settings at server side but it didn't helped.

Observed one case that when the Matrikon OPC Simulation is installed on client machine  in that case i am able to connect to the remote OPCDA server from client machine.

Can someone guide me with that Why we are able to connect with OPCDA remote server When the server is installed on client machine as well.

Is there any particular settings that happen during the Matrikon server installation that is making the OPCDA remote connection successful.

Comment: I need to know the type of database and connection string.  It is probably a credential issue, but can be other things.  You may need a driver installed.  You also should publish application and deploy on client machine so the dlls on client are upgraded to work with application.

Comment: I am not sure which driver i required to install on client machine in order to connect to OPCDA remote server. Also i have installed my application that is a window service on client machine but it is not able to connect to remote OPCD server untill i am installing the Matrikon OPC Simulator server on client machine as well

Comment: I think you are missing Component Service.  See : https://www.kepware.com/getattachment/04042e47-c690-467c-a931-a1ca126575db/Remote-OPC-DA-Quick-Start-Guide-DCOM.pdf